# Recyclerview scrollToPosition doesn't work with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

So I have a Recyclerview within a NestedScrollView. When I say recycleview.scrollToPosition(X) or recycleview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(X) it doesn't work at all.

If I move the recycleview out from the nestedScrollView it work fine, but I can't do it , because of the layout structure!
Any idea?

Comment: I know that If I would scroll with finger NestedScrollView would trigger scroll, and I would never be able to scroll RecyclerView (unless I go to bottom I think). Anyway, it looks like weird layout, you sure you need to implement it this way?

Comment: Yes, I do. So we have a the main image on the top of the recycleView and when you scroll it the image should collapse parallax. In order to do I need the NestedScrollView